# Construct $n$-dimensional mollifier by using cartesian product

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $\rho$ be a mollifier in $\mathbb{R}^n$, that is $\rho\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$, $\rho\ge 0$, $\textrm {supp$\rho$}\subset \{|x|_2\le 1\}$ and $\int_{\textrm{supp$\rho$}}\rho(e)\,de=1$.

The usual construction of $\rho$ is by
$$\rho(x) = \begin{cases} e^{-1/(1-|x|_2^2)}/I_n& \text{ if } |x| < 1\\
                 0& \text{ if } |x|\geq 1,
                 \end{cases}
$$
where $I_n$ is a normalizing factor.

However, why don't we construct the $n$-dimensional $\rho$ by using the cartesian product of one-dimensional mollifier, in the sense that
$$
\rho(x)=\frac{1}{I_1^n}\rho_1(x_1)\cdots \rho_1(x_n),
$$
where $\rho_1$ is a one-dimensional mollifier, and $I_1$ is the scaling factor for (one-dimensional) $\rho_1$? Of course, now the support of $\rho$ will be $(\textrm{supp$\rho_1$})^n$, but since  I don't think it affects the analysis.